# one gang wall plate with three toggle switches

Tags: electrical

I am looking to replace a one gang wall plate  (3 toggle switches.).  Going to a big box store (lowes) I was told that they do not carry such an item .  From what I can see  a 2 gang plate with three toggle switches is most common.
The home was built in 1943.  Is such a plate even available any longer (one gang)??  I recall an illustration of what "gang" means in your answer to a another person's question and I saw the plate cover I was looking for.

Comment: It's not clear who you're referring to by "in your answer to a another person" - there are many people here who post answers. And it would probably help if you added a photo of the plate you're trying to replace.

Comment: Are you replacing both the switch and the wall plate, or just the wall plate?  Are you open to replacing the switch even?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to replace your existing triple-pole triple-throw switch with a more modern version that takes a standard Decora front plate.

Eaton makes such a switch, it's available from Home Depot model number 7729W-SP, and looks like this:

[image]

Then you just need a Decora front plate like this:

[image]

Comment: I think this is more correctly referred to as a triple single pole single throw switch. I think a triple pole, triple throw switch would have three circuits controlled by one toggle, and would have three positions, all of them live.

Comment: Triple single pole is correct. Tripple/Tripple as the answer suggest would have more connection points that could fit in a 4 square box.